# Coldfusion crontime incorrectly running on weekend

Tags: coldfusion, cron, scheduled-tasks, cronexpression

I have a scheduled task that needs to run three times a day, on each weekday. The setup surrounding the task is Coldfusion, and it is in the Crontime format. It should run at 11:30, 15:45 and 18:30 server time.

For some reason the task is occasionally running on weekends, which it should not do.

Here are the three strings for each of the days:

```
0 30 11 ? * 1-5
0 45 15 ? * 1-5
0 30 18 ? * 1-5
```

Can anyone point out to me why the task is sometimes running on weekends? Is there a mistake in my string?

The Coldfusion crontime documentation can be found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d31851899e53a51353e870493-8000.html):

Comment: I handle this thing in the ColdFusion template itself.  In fact, since I have access to holiday data, I have written functions to tell whether or not any given date is a busisness day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [This](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.80185997,d.d2s&ion=1&biw=1680&bih=959&q=cache:http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson06.html&ech=1&psi=jQRzVIGJB9P1auS3gNAJ.1416823949862.3&ei=jQRzVIGJB9P1auS3gNAJ&emsg=NCSR&noj=1), 1 = Sunday.

> Days-of-Week can be specified as values between 1 and 7 (1 = Sunday) or by using the strings SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI and SAT.

Try replacing 1-5 with MON-FRI?

> An example of a complete cron-expression is the string "0 0 12 ? * WED" - which means "every Wednesday at 12:00:00 pm".
>
> Individual sub-expressions can contain ranges and/or lists. For example, the day of week field in the previous (which reads "WED") example could be replaced with "MON-FRI", "MON,WED,FRI", or even "MON-WED,SAT".

Comment: I should have taken a closer look at that page, Thank you